# PreparedStatement ignoring millisecond

Tags: java, sql-server, timestamp, prepared-statement, milliseconds

I'm having a problem where setTimestamp method for PreparedStatement is ignoring the millisecond. I'm using Java 1.8 and Sqlserver with JDBC Driver

```
String SQL = "Select x from Table where time > ?"
PreparedStatement prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(SQL);
prepStmt.setTimestamp(1,tstamp.valueOf("2018-09-14 14:47:06.827"));
ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
```

I got the wrong result. Seems like it executed

```
Select x from Table where time > 2018-09-14 14:47:06 // WRONG
```

instead of

```
Select x from Table where time > 2018-09-14 14:47:06.827 // RIGHT
```

How can I do setTimestamp and include millisec with it?

Comment: Does the query work with millisecond if you run it outside of your program? (E.g inside sql-server studio)

Comment: What does `tstamp.valueOf("2018-09-14 14:47:06.827")` produce?

Comment: @dustytrash Yea. It works perfectly fine in other programs like DBeaver or SQL workbench

Comment: @dustytrash It just convert String value of 2018-09-14 14:47:06.827 to Timestamp value with millisecond 2018-09-14 14:47:06.827. It stays the same

Comment: Is your problem the same as this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445807/mariadb-jdbc-settimestamp-truncates-milliseconds#answer-25803063

Comment: The mariaDB has useFractionalSeconds option in databaseURL, but this is SQLServer so I'm not quite sure if it's the same issue tho

Comment: Please share relevant parts of the table definition (mainly the data type of the `time` column) with example data.

Comment: Column Name: time
Data Type: Datetime
Length: 23
Scale: 3

Example data: 2018-10-17 21:08:31

Comment: The `Timestamp` class is long outdated and poorly designed. It’s unlikely to solve your problem, but in any case I’d use for example `prepStmt.setObject1, Instant.parse("2018-09-14T14:47:06.827Z"));` or `prepStmt.setObject1, LocalDateTime.parse("2018-09-14T14:47:06.827"));`.

Comment: What's `tstamp`? Are you calling a static method on an instance of `Timestamp`?

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for your suggestion, but it didn't work. I'm calling setTimestamp method from PreparedStatement class. It requires 2 parameters (int index, timestamp x) When I pass in the tstamp value, seems like it ignore the millisecond value

Comment: My suggestion requires at least Java 8 and at least JDBC 4.2. If you have those, I’d be curious what error message or unexpected behaviour you get.

Comment: @OleV.V. My reading of the JDBC specification is that Instant is not one of the supported date/time types, though LocalDateTime is.

Comment: @VGR @OleV.V. Indeed, I just searched through the JDBC 4.2 and 4.3 specs, PDF files downloaded from [JSR 221](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221). The 4.2 spec says: Added support to map java.time.LocalOffsetDateTime to JDBC TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE. But, there is no such class as that! Furthermore, no mention of `Instant` in either 4.2 or 4.3. Appendix B.4 in both 4.2/4.3 maps the JDBC/SQL type `TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE` with `OffsetDateTime`. Perhaps this covers the unusual case of dbs that save the zone/offset, rather than UTC as is commonly done.

Comment: @VGR @OleV.V. Anyways, practically speaking, I expect JDBC drivers are implementing support for `Instant`. But if not, or if you want to abide by the spec strictly, apparently we should be doing this: `myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , myInstant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ) ;` to convert our `Instant` object to a `OffsetDateTime` object. By the way, neither 4.2 nor 4.3 mentions `ZonedDateTime` at all.